# Suppressing Error Highlighting of Macros in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

### The Issue

Well, I have this really interesting macro set

```
#define __macro_3_opt_args(_0, _1, _2, _3, name, ...) name
#define _macro_3_opt_args_(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) __macro_3_opt_args(, ##__VA_ARGS__, arg3, arg2, arg1, arg0)(__VA_ARGS__)


#define __padding_id(size, id) uint8_t _padding_##id##_ [size]
#define ____padding_line(size, line) __padding_id(size, ln##line) //adding `ln` prefix
#define ___padding_line(size, line) ____padding_line(size, line) //expanding `__LINE__` macro first
#define __padding_line(size) ___padding_line(size, __LINE__)

#define _padding_(...) _macro_2_opt_args_(, __padding_line, __padding_id, __VA_ARGS__)

#define offset_struct union
#define _offset_zero_member(type, name) type name
#define _offset_member(type, name, offset) struct { __padding_id(offset, to_##name); type name; }
#define offset_member(type, name, ...) _macro_3_opt_args_(, , _offset_zero_member, _offset_member, type, name, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

But if I try to use it (like this:)

```
offset_struct Test {
    offset_member (int, header);
    offset_member (void*, data, 64);
} test;
```

```
//Let's say this two code snippets are in a same file
```

VS highlights the `offset_member` macro *"calls"* as errors *(I use Microsoft's C/C++ Extension)*.
When I lookup VS Code's macro expansion
it shows `struct { uint8_t _padding_to__ []; void*, data,64 ; }`
instead of `struct { uint8_t _padding_to_data_ [64]; void* data; }` *(what GCC sees)*

### The Question

How do I make VS ignore the macro expansion?
Can I use some magic `#pragma` for that?
Or is there a config that does it?

Comment: The error is correctly given. You need to remove the space between the macro name and the opening parenthesis. -- Expanding `offset_struct` should give you `union`, not `struct`. Is this your real source?

Comment: @the busybee Well, I tried removing the space but it did nothing _(as I expected)_ the error in VS still stays. If the error was correct, then why did it compile just fine (no warnings, nothing...). Also you might have misread `offset_member` as `offset_struct`.

Comment: Oh yes, I confused this with macro _definitions_. Sorry for the noise. I can confirm your result from GCC with the source given in one file. -- How do you "present" the macros to the source, do you `#include`, perhaps with some conditional that VSC evaluates differently than GCC? You might like to [edit] your question with a [example], with emphasis on "complete". -- As long as VSC is just little more than an editor, I rather stick to "real" IDEs. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this would be enough. It is as you say, I include my header `macros.h` _(that contains those macros)_ in `test.c` where I wanted to test if everything work before I continue, but I didn't think that matters since **VS keeps highlighting them as errors** even **when I put them in a single file.** _I'm going to mention that in the question in a moment_

Comment: [This](https://www.onlinegdb.com/5YBCFlsVM) is a same code that I have in the Visual Studio. _(Disclaimer: I don't know how that page works so I don't know how long will that link remain functional and this is why I didn't want to mention it in my question)_

Comment: Well, then I'm out. I have no deeper experience with VSC. Good luck!